# Using Overflow Sites and Scriptblock Plugin (howto fix strange js behaviour)

Tags: support, javascript

This is more of a notice for users than question. Those of you who use scriptblock may have noticed that some features like voting don't work if you only allow scripts from the main sites to work. It looks like the team has moved some assets to [sstatic.net](http://sstatic.net), so you now have to allow this site for everything to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

It should also be said that if you use blocking techniques, don't be surprised when things don't work properly 100% of the time.